# 'X' no longer or no longer 'X'

Tags: grammar, formal-language, informal-language

What is the difference between following sentences:

"*This outpost is no longer used*".

"*No longer this outpost is used*".

Do both of the given sentences grammatically carry the same meaning? Ive thought so far that scructure in the second sentence is used most likely in poems and grammatically alright. Nevertheless, a non-native english speaker mocked me and said this usage is grammatically not alright and now it beats me.

Comment: No, it isn't right. In poetic/literary language it would be possible to say _No longer is this outpost used_.

Comment: @KateBunting No more the wild rover, no never no more.... (etc).

Answer (score 1):

The former is valid.

The latter could be reworded to "No longer is this output used". As Kate pointed out, you could use this wording in poetry or literature, but it sounds awkward otherwise.